# Inserting Data into Database with Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to Update user Profile after they Login, It works well and says PROFILE UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY but nothing inserted on the Database Table, so in essence, the View shows nothing of the Updated form fields. Please anyone with an idea of where i am getting this wrong will be highly appreciated, Thanks.

CONTROLLER Update FUNCTION

```
    public function update(Request $request)
    {

        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required|numeric',
            'country' => 'required',
            'gender' => 'required',
            'birthday' => 'required',
            'fb' => 'url',
            'twitter' => 'url',
            'gp' => 'url',
            'instagram' => 'url',
            'personal_site' => 'url',
            'aboutme' => 'url',
            'linkedin' => 'url',
            'pinterest' => 'url'

        ];

        $data= $request->all();
        $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
        if($validator->fails()){
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        }
        $user = Auth::user();

        $user->name = $data['name'];
        $user->email = $data['email'];
        $user->phone = $data['phone'];
        $user->country = $data['country'];
        $user->birthday = $data['birthday'];
        $user->address = $data['address'];
        if($user->save()) {
            $profile_id = $user->id;
            $profile = Profile::find($profile_id);
            if(count($profile) > 0) {
            $profile->gender = $data['gender'];
            $profile->city = $data['city'];
            $profile->state = $data['state'];
            $profile->aboutmyself = $data['aboutmyself'];
            $profile->fb = $data['fb'];
            $profile->twitter = $data['twitter'];
            $profile->gp = $data['gp'];
            $profile->instagram = $data['instagram'];
            $profile->personal_site = $data['personal_site'];
            $profile->aboutme = $data['aboutme'];
            $profile->linkedin = $data['linkedin'];
            $profile->pinterest = $data['pinterest'];
            // $profile = $user->profile()->save($profile);
            $profile->save();

}
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withInfo("Something went wrong. Please, try again");
        }
        return redirect()->route('profile')->withSuccess("Your Profile Successfully Updated.");

    }
```

MY VIEW (profile-edit.blade.php)

```
 <div class="form-group row">
              {!! Form::model($user, array('route' => 'post.edit.profile', 'method' => 'post', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) !!}

                 {!! Form::label('name', "Full Name", array('class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label')) !!}
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                      {!! Form::text('name', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Your Full Name', 'required' => 'required')) !!}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                 {!! Form::label('email', "Email Address", array('class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label')) !!}
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">
                                <i class="material-icons md-18 text-muted">mail</i>
                            </span>
                   {!! Form::email('email', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '', 'required' => 'required')) !!}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                 {!! Form::label('phone', "Phone Number", array('class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label')) !!}
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">
                                <i class="material-icons md-18 text-muted">mail</i>
                            </span>
                  {!! Form::text('phone', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'e.g. +8801711223344', 'required' => 'required')) !!}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="form-group row">
                {!! Form::label('gender', "Gender", array('class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label')) !!}
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    {!! Form::select('gender', $gender, array('class' => 'c-select form-control', 'id' => '', 'required' => 'required')) !!}
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="form-group row">
               {!! Form::label('birthday', "Birthday", array('class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label')) !!}
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">
                                <i class="material-icons md-18 text-muted">language</i>
                            </span>

                    {!! Form::text('birthday', null, array('class' => 'datepicker form-control', 'placeholder' => '01/28/2016','id' => 'birthday', 'required' => 'required')) !!}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
               {!! Form::label('address', "Address", array('class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label')) !!}
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">
                                <i class="material-icons md-18 text-muted">language</i>
                            </span>
                    {!! Form::text('address', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Street No., Area...','id' => 'address', 'required' => 'required')) !!}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
              {!! Form::label('city', "City", array('class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label')) !!}
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">
                                <i class="material-icons md-18 text-muted">language</i>
                            </span>
                    {!! Form::text('city', $user->profile->city, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'City', 'required' => 'required')) !!}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
               <div class="form-group row">
             {!! Form::label('state', "State", array('class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label')) !!}
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">
                                <i class="material-icons md-18 text-muted">language</i>
                            </span>
                    {!! Form::text('state', $user->profile->state,  array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'State', 'required' => 'required')) !!}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="form-group row">
                {!! Form::label('country', "Country", array('class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label')) !!}
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                     {!! Form::text('country', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Country','id' => '')) !!}

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>




                           <div class="form-group row">
              {!! Form::label('aboutmyself', "About Me", array('class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label')) !!}
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">
                                <i class="material-icons md-18 text-muted">language</i>
                            </span>
                   {!! Form::textarea('aboutmyself', Auth::user()->profile->aboutmyself, array('class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => 4, 'placeholder' => 'About Yourself')) !!}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
             {!! Form::label('fb', "Facebook Link", array('class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label')) !!}
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">
                                <i class="material-icons md-18 text-muted">language</i>
                            </span>
                   {!! Form::text('fb', $user->profile->fb, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'https://facebook.com/username')) !!}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group row">
             {!! Form::label('twitter', "Twitter Link", array('class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label')) !!}
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">
                                <i class="material-icons md-18 text-muted">language</i>
                            </span>
                   {!! Form::text('twitter', $user->profile->twitter, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'https://twitter.com/username')) !!}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

                          <div class="form-group row">
            {!! Form::label('gp', "Google+ Link", array('class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label')) !!}
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">
                                <i class="material-icons md-18 text-muted">language</i>
                            </span>
                   {!! Form::text('gp', $user->profile->gp, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'https://plus.google.com/+username')) !!}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group row">
           {!! Form::label('personal_site', "Personal Site", array('class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label')) !!}
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">
                                <i class="material-icons md-18 text-muted">language</i>
                            </span>
                    {!! Form::text('personal_site', $user->profile->personal_site, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'http://www.mywebsite.me')) !!}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

               <div class="form-group row">
          {!! Form::label('instagram', "Instagram Link", array('class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label')) !!}
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">
                                <i class="material-icons md-18 text-muted">language</i>
                            </span>
                    {!! Form::text('instagram', $user->profile->instagram, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'https://www.instagram.com/username')) !!}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group row">
         {!! Form::label('linkedin', "LinkedIn Link", array('class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label')) !!}
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">
                                <i class="material-icons md-18 text-muted">language</i>
                            </span>
                    {!! Form::text('linkedin', $user->profile->linkedin, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'https://www.linkedin.com/username')) !!}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group row">
          {!! Form::label('pinterest', "Pinterest Link", array('class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label')) !!}
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">
                                <i class="material-icons md-18 text-muted">language</i>
                            </span>
                    {!! Form::text('pinterest', $user->profile->pinterest, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'https://www.pinterest.com/username')) !!}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

             <!-- <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="password" class="col-sm-3 form-control-label">Change Password</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">
                                <i class="material-icons md-18 text-muted">lock</i>
                            </span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter new password">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div> -->
              <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-3">
                  <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left">
                     {!! Form::submit('Save Changes', array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) !!}
                    </div>
                   <!-- <div class="media-body media-middle p-l-1">
                      <label class="c-input c-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" checked>
                        <span class="c-indicator"></span> Subscribe to Newsletter
                      </label>
                    </div> -->
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

User MODEL (User.php)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword,EntrustUserTrait {
        EntrustUserTrait::can as may;
        Authorizable::can insteadof EntrustUserTrait;
    }

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function profile(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Profile','user_id','id');
    }

    public function pending(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\PendingTransfers', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function transaction(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Transaction', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

ROUTE

```
Route::group(array('middleware' => 'auth'), function()
{

    Route::get('logout', ['as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@logout']);
    Route::get('profile', ['as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'UsersController@profile']);
    Route::get('edit-profile', ['as' => 'edit.profile', 'uses' => 'UsersController@edit']);
    Route::post('edit-profile', ['as' => 'post.edit.profile', 'uses' => 'UsersController@update']);
    Route::post('edit-photo', ['as' => 'post.edit.photo', 'uses' => 'UsersController@photoUpdate']);
    Route::get('dashboard', array('as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@dashboard'));
    Route::get('change-password', array('as' => 'password.change', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@changePassword'));
    Route::post('change-password', array('as' => 'password.doChange', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@doChangePassword'));
```

UPDATE: Thanks for the Prompt response but that didn't fix it though, Am thinking the Fault might be from the CONTROLLER FUNCTION at this point:

```
if($user->save()) {
            $profile_id = $user->id;
            $profile = Profile::find($profile_id);
            if(count($profile) > 0) {
            $profile->gender = $data['gender'];
            $profile->city = $data['city'];
            $profile->state = $data['state'];
            $profile->aboutmyself = $data['aboutmyself'];
            $profile->fb = $data['fb'];
            $profile->twitter = $data['twitter'];
            $profile->gp = $data['gp'];
            $profile->instagram = $data['instagram'];
            $profile->personal_site = $data['personal_site'];
            $profile->aboutme = $data['aboutme'];
            $profile->linkedin = $data['linkedin'];
            $profile->pinterest = $data['pinterest'];
            // $profile = $user->profile()->save($profile);
            $profile->save();
```

OR Probably from the VIEW Opening Form route/variable $user

```
 {!! Form::model($user, array('route' => 'post.edit.profile', 'method' => 'post', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) !!}
```

Comment: Seriously! Do you expect anyone to read all this code?

Comment: Are you actually pulling a profile to save? `Log::info($profile);` after your `Profile::find()` and before `count($profile)`.

Comment: Looks like you need to pass the `$user` variable when redirecting to your `profile` route.

Comment: Change how you find a profile $profile = Profile::findOrFail($profile_id). If this throws error then it mean no profile exists with that id in database. So, where you perform the check If(count($profile) > 0) this block never executes if no profile exists and $profile->save() never executes.